# Unable to install wget

Tags: shell, command-line, homebrew, wget

My MacBook Air was equipped with macOS Mojave Version 10.14.6.
I cannot install wget even if I have checked brew version.

```
brew --version
```

The output is :

```
Homebrew 3.3.13
Homebrew/homebrew-core (no Git repository)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision fb6ec06d8b; last commit 2022-01-31)
```

When I tried to install wget:

```
brew install wget
```

This is the result:

```
Warning: No available formula with the name "ca-certificates".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Running `brew update --preinstall`...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision
Warning: No available formula with the name "wget".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

This problem has bothered me for a long while...

Comment: Can you run `brew doctor` for me?

Comment: Sorry for late reply..

Comment: the information in brew doctor: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w21xDzV51Pydlyy3oc_oyKNR9-qi5uWB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I install wget with Conda install in the end, but I am still curious about how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 26):

Eventually, I solved this problem by running the following code:

```
brew update-reset
brew install wget
```

I hoped this may help others.

Comment: I solved my problem with this comment, by running` brew update-reset` before installing wget

Answer (score 7):

Problem could be 'Homebrew/homebrew-core not tapped properly'. Executing these two commands resolved the issue for me.

```
rm -rf "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core"
brew tap homebrew/core
```